# Format a period with DurationFormatUtils in a nice way

Tags: java, apache-commons

This works very well:

```
out.println(DurationFormatUtils.formatPeriod(
                        new Date().getTime(),
                        match.getStartingTime().getTime(),
                        "d H"));
```

But now I would like to have some nicer format

```
out.println(DurationFormatUtils.formatPeriod(
                        new Date().getTime(),
                        match.getStartingTime().getTime(),
                        "d days H hours left"));
```

But as aspected this gives output as

> 45 a01101 4 hour1101 left

Is there a simple solution for this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It would appear that they base their formatting on the [SimpleDateFormatter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html?is-external=true) and the escape character there is '

So your code would be something like this:

```
"d 'days' H 'hours left'"
```